# Can i get the event about file operation on OneDrive?

Tags: sharepoint, onedrive

As we know, we can add remote event receiver to the list. then if there is a item added or updated in this list, we can get the event send by sharepoint 2013 online.
This is the info about event in sharepoint:
[https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.SharePoint.SPItemEventReceiver_methods.aspx]

- So can we have this kind of method in OneDrive(skydrive) too?
- It means when there is a file added in the OneDrive, then my App can get this event and take some action on this file.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The OneDrive API does not (yet!) support subscriptions to events.  Please visit the [OneDrive user voice](https://onedrive.uservoice.com/forums/262982-onedrive/category/89523-developer) and make/vote up topics that you'd like to see implemented.

To question #2 the [view.changes api](http://onedrive.github.io/items/view_changes.htm) allows for applications to easily know which changes have happened since the application last queried OneDrive might be just what you need without subscriptions.